# Grails save() doesn't save if called after relationship is added

Tags: grails

I have two domain classes - Person has many Books. If I create a
Person, call save(), then create+add Books to the Person, everything
is persisted to the database. If I create a Person, then create+add
Books, followed by save(), nothing get persisted.

Example code:

```
class Person {
   ...
   static hasMany = [books: Book]
}

class Book {
   ...
   static belongsTo = [person: Person]
}
```

Works, saves to database:

```
def person = new Person(...).save()
def book = new Book(...)
person.addToBooks(book)
```

Doesn't not work, doesn't save to database:

```
def person = new Person(...)
def book = new Book(...)
person.addToBooks(book)
person.save()
```

Why is this?

I'm running this from the Groovy console. I've tried calling `ctx.sessionFactory.currentSession.clear()` which doesn't help.

**Resolved:** The Book I was attaching to the Person had errors in it. By calling `person.hasErrors()` and `getErrors()` I was able to see that my Book was failing validation. This was being run from the Grails console so there wasn't any validation error messages.

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually flush the hibernate session like this:

```
person.save(flush:true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure but I presume it's because save() sets the ID of the Person which would be required to be able to add a Book to it's book collection.

I'd suggest doing some googling on Hibernate collection behaviour, it could be the way Hibernate works or maybe it's a bug in the version of Grails you're using.

Another thing to try is forcing a flush with person.save(flush:true)